# Identify a data entry without changing the ID

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create an update form. It is supposed to take values from the text boxes on the form and update that registry using the ID's autonumber as an identifier. It says I cannot edit the ID even though I don't think I am.

```vb
Private Sub edit_Click()

'Will edit the currently selected record
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE DataInput " & _
    " SET ID=" & Me.txtID & _
    ", [Date]='" & Me.Date & "'" & _
    ", [Time Up]='" & Me.txttimeup & "'" & _
    ", [Notes]='" & Me.CboNotes & "'" & _
    ", [Time Down]='" & Me.txtTimeDown & "'" & _
    " WHERE ID=" & Me.txtID.Tag

        Me.txtID.Tag = ""

'refresh data on form
DataInput_subform.Form.Requery

'Disable Update Button
Me.edit.Enabled = False

'Enable Edit Button
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True

'Clear texts
cmdClear_Click
```

Comment: You cannot set the ID field so just remove from Set list but still use in your where clause.

Comment: When I do that it gives another error saying there are duplicates in the field, apparently it needs a non duplicate value for some reason but I'm not sure why

Comment: If there are duplicates in the field then its not a primary key and you won't be able to use it alone in Where clause

Comment: sorry i wasn't being clear, I mean the other values have duplicates and it couln't identify them because of it. Would moving the where clause to the top of the list help or will it not work like that?

Comment: No the where clause is in the right place. It doesn't matter if the other fields have duplicates. Can you poat your new sql statement?

Comment: Why are you using Me.txtID.Tag ? - The tag property isn't anything to do with your data? Surely you simply want Me.txtID

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE DataInput " & _
        " SET [Date]=" & Me.Date & _
        ", [Time Up]='" & Me.txttimeup & "'" & _
        ", [Notes]='" & Me.CboNotes & "'" & _
        ", [Time Down]='" & Me.txtTimeDown & "'" & _
        " WHERE ID='" & Me.txtID.Tag
            Me.txtID.Tag = ""`

Comment: The Tag was set from another prompt to get the data

Comment: It seems irreverent all the same. If your current ID is correct then simply use it. The tag is almost certainly a string - ID is a number. Also if your [Date] field (Please change it's name  - Date is a reserved word in Access) is an actual date you will need to enclose it with # symbols.

Comment: did what you said, now getting error 3075: Syntax error in string in query expression 'ID='2'.

Comment: That's because ID is a number and you are putting quotes around it. See my answer for a better way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting your code in a more readable way and add a debug like

```
Dim sSql As String

sSql = "UPDATE DataInput SET [Date]=#" & Format(Me.Date,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#, " 
sSql = sSql & "[Time Up] = '" & Me.txttimeup & "', [Notes] ='" & Me.CboNotes & "', " 
sSql = sSql & "[Time Down] = '" & Me.txtTimeDown & "' "
sSql = sSql & "WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID & " ;" 

Debug.Print sSql
CurrentDb.Execute sSql
```

Comment: No problem , or trouble - glad it you now have it working.